# GSON Adding java object to json array

Tags: java, json, gson

I have json `{"name": "John", "tests":["apple"]}`. In my Java code I want to update this json throught gson - add string field to json array and save to file to have this json - `{"name": "John", "tests":["apple", "pinapple"]}`. So is there a way how ? Java class for my json look like this:

```
public class Test{
    private String name;
    private List<String> tests;

    // Getters/Setters
}
```

Reading json in java like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

try (Reader reader = new FileReader("D:\\file.json")) {
    Test js = gson.fromJson(reader, Test.class);
    System.out.println(js.getName());   
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Doing this my new json file is empty:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try (Reader reader = new FileReader("D:\\file.json")) {
        Test test = gson.fromJson(reader, Test.class);
        System.out.println(test.getName());
        test.getTests().add("pinapple");
        String newJson = gson.toJson(test);
        System.out.println(newJson);
        gson.toJson(test, new FileWriter("D:\\file.json"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `ts.getTests().add("pinapple")`?

Comment: Yes, but i need to save new json file and I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test test = gson.fromJson(reader, Test.class);
```

Once you have your `Test` object do:

```
test.getTests().add("pineapple");
```

Now you have the `pineapple` in your array. You can make your JSON string:

```
String newJson = gson.toJson(test);
System.out.println(newJson);
```

or write it back in the same file

```
gson.toJson(test, new FileWriter("D:\\file.json"));
```

**EDIT**: Whole code

```
String fileName = "D:\\file.json";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Test test = null;
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName)) {
    test = gson.fromJson(reader, Test.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

test.getTests().add("pineapple");
String newJson = gson.toJson(test);
System.out.println(newJson);

try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileName)) {
    gson.toJson(test, writer);
}
```

Comment: `gson.toJson(test, new FileWriter("D:\\file.json"));` dont work. My new file is empty.

Comment: try to do the write in an other try/catch.

Comment: @M.Barabas I edited my answer with the whole working code.